# How to pass state value from parent element to child in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In my code I have a tab menu and I want to switch in between these tabs using a button. I want to pass the value of these tabs into my onclick function for my button so it can navigate between the tabs.

For example:

```
<Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this._handleChange}>
     <Tab label="1" value={1}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange} />
     </Tab>
     <Tab label="2" value={2}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange} />
     </Tab>
     <Tab label="3" value={3}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange} />
     </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

My _handleChange function simply sets the state to the value of the next tab

```
_handleChange: function(value) {
    this.setState({
      value: value,
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
```

I need to somehow linkup the onTouchTap event with the onChange event from the main tabs element but I am not sure how to do that. My main goal is to navigate between the three tabs available: when the next button is clicked on tab1, it will shift to tab2, and then onto tab3, and finally back to tab1.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish that? I am also using material UI if those elements look foreign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this._handleChange}>
     <Tab label="1" value={1}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange.bind(this, 2)} />
     </Tab>
     <Tab label="2" value={2}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange.bind(this, 3)} />
     </Tab>
     <Tab label="3" value={3}>
         <RaisedButton label="Next" onTouchTap={this._handleChange.bind(this, 1)} />
     </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

While siu answer is correct, just to note that setState() is an asynchronous call,

your `console.log` right after

```
this.setState({
  value: value,
});
```

may output differently as you expected